# Cannot find module 'ionic-angular/navigation/navigation-container'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I was working on `Swipeable tabs for Ionic 2` using `ionic2-super-tabs`
and while building the  project got an error 
`Cannot find module 'ionic-angular/navigation/navigation-container'`
Any help will be really useful.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and updating version of ionic-angular solved an error.

So, in the terminal you are using go to your projects directory and try running this command:

**npm install ionic-angular@3.6.1 --save**

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code in terminal and It worked for me.

```
npm install ionic-angular@latest --save
```